# Cyrillic Font Support for Sql query

Tags: sql-server-2008

i have database with Cyrillic Font

font look like:" A Б Ц Д Е Ф"

So when i go " SELECT FROM Table WHERE Something Like 'Бла' "
Returns Nothing.

How to make it work.

Comment: What is your database's default collation? Also are you missing any wildcards for your `LIKE` expression? (i.e. why are you using `LIKE` rather than `=`). Any different if you try `N'Бла'`? (note the `N` prefix)

Comment: Your first post make it work my app. using  N prefix it works now thanks.

Comment: LIKE is more reliable for strings as i know

Comment: Not really. If your strings might happen to contain any special pattern characters such as `%` or `_` it will return unexpected results. `=` is perfectly reliable!

Comment: @Starter why is `LIKE` "more reliable for strings"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to use the `N` prefix to represent a Unicode string literal if those characters aren't representable in single byte form in your database's default collation.

```
 SELECT *
 FROM   Table
 WHERE  Something LIKE N'Бла'
```